# Use typesVersions and types declare dts path ,get cannot find module error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, web

**Updated**

When I  change `./dist/*` to `./dist/index.d.ts` and it works.

Why its working?

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "./dist/index.d.ts" // change ./dist/* to ./dist/index.d.ts
      ]
    }
  },
```

---

**The original question**

1. I have developed a TypeScript library called `@some/utils` and published it to npm.
2. The `@some/utils` bundle output looks like the image in the first link provided. Each module (browser.ts, copy.ts, etc.) bundles to the same name `.js` and `.d.ts` files, while index.ts only exports from the module, as shown in the second link.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

3. When attempting to import `@some/utils` in another project, I receive the error message `"Cannot find module '@some/utils' or its corresponding type declarations."`, as shown in the code snippet provided.

```js
import { canSupportCssVar } from '@some/utils' // Cannot find module '@some/utils' or its corresponding type declarations
import { loadCss } from '@some/utils/dom'  // works fine
```

4. I have declared typesVersions and types in `@some/utils`'s `package.json` file as displayed below.

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "./dist/*"
      ]
    }
  },
```

5. I have read the documentation found at `https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html` and modified `typesVersions` and `types`, yet the issue remains unsolved. Where might I have gone wrong?
6. My goals are to have the following code work properly:

```js
import { canSupportCssVar } from '@some/utils'
import { loadCss } from '@some/utils/dom'
```

My golas is above code are all working